# How do you filter project tags in Azure Devops?

Tags: reporting, azure-boards

The list of projects we've got in Azure DevOps is rapidly growing and growing.  It makes it difficult to focus on areas that need attention across the department though, and is taking a lot of Admin time to try and separate these out for management meetings and things like that.

I can see you can add tags to projects in devops but there doesn't seem to be a way to filter on them. Am I missing something?  Is there a better way? Do I need to look in the Marketplace for a particular extension??

Comment: Would love to know the same thing! Why do they let you tag projects *if the tags don't do anything!*

Answer (score 1):

You can use queries to explore tags. Go to

1. Azure DevOps - Boards
2. Click on Queries
3. Click on New Query
4. Within *Field* type "Tag" and select from the *Value* dropdown (this contains a list of all tags)
5. Run query

If you want all tags associated with a specific sprint then

1. Add a new clause
2. Confirm that "and" is pre-selected
3. Within *Field* type "iteration path" and select current sprint number from the *Value* dropdown

Answer (score 0):

### Looks like it is not possible to filter by tags

[User reported a bug here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/project-tags-cannot-be-searchedfiltered/413640):

> Azure DevOps allows you to set project tags...However, neither the
> top-level Azure DevOps "Search" nor the "Filter projects" box allow
> you to search/filter based on these tags.

Microsoft tech declared that it is not a bug and closed the issue!

> tags are used for marking the project with it's properties. It's not
> for searching or filtering projects

Answer (score 0):

From Microsoft:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/add-tags-to-work-items?view=azure-devops#query-for-work-items-based-on-tags

> To query work items based on tags, add a clause for each tag you want
> to use to support your query.
>
> For example, here we query for all work items that are tagged either `Web` or `Service`.
> [image: Example of query using tags]